# Idiomatic way to generate a random alphanumeric string in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin

I can generate a random sequence of numbers in a certain range like the following:

```
fun ClosedRange<Int>.random() = Random().nextInt(endInclusive - start) +  start
fun generateRandomNumberList(len: Int, low: Int = 0, high: Int = 255): List<Int> {
  (0..len-1).map {
    (low..high).random()
  }.toList()
}
```

Then I'll have to extend `List` with:

```
fun List<Char>.random() = this[Random().nextInt(this.size)]
```

Then I can do:

```
fun generateRandomString(len: Int = 15): String{
  val alphanumerics = CharArray(26) { it -> (it + 97).toChar() }.toSet()
      .union(CharArray(9) { it -> (it + 48).toChar() }.toSet())
  return (0..len-1).map {
      alphanumerics.toList().random()
  }.joinToString("")
}
```

But maybe there's a better way?

Comment: Holger Brandl for the lazy way.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Assuming you have a specific set of source characters (`source` in this snippet), you could do this:

```
val source = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"
java.util.Random().ints(outputStrLength, 0, source.length)
        .asSequence()
        .map(source::get)
        .joinToString("")
```

Which gives strings like "LYANFGNPNI" for outputStrLength = 10.

The two important bits are

1. `Random().ints(length, minValue, maxValue)` which produces a stream of *length* random numbers each from *minValue* to *maxValue-1*, and
2. `asSequence()` which converts the not-massively-useful `IntStream` into a much-more-useful `Sequence<Int>`.

Comment: As a Kotlin newby I was look for this solution - very cool! However I would use `source.length` instead of `source.length - 1`, otherwise one wont ever see a Z. The ints range parameter marks an exclusive upper bound.

Comment: Well spotted. Very interesting idea of the Java8 API designers to make this (almost) the only exclusive bound-describing parameter in Java...

Comment: Fixed now, in example and description.

Comment: I get an unresolved reference on the `.asSequence()` as `IntStream` doesn't have that method

Comment: Using `kotlinc-jvm 1.2.30 (JRE 1.8.0_162-b12)`

Comment: Are you including `kotlin.streams`? It's [an extension method](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.streams/java.util.stream.-int-stream/as-sequence.html), not provided in java.

Comment: @PaulHicks Thanks... Adding `import kotlin.streams.asSequence` to the top helped. Weird that IntelliJ didn't suggest that at all.

Comment: @PaulHicks you can use `.toArray()` instead of `.asSequence()` without the need to import additional methods.

Comment: Yep that is a good way to go. Since your source length is unlikely to be large, you won't notice any performance difference.

Comment: I suggest updating this answer with Kotlin version used since Random.ints() is not possible with Kotlin 1.3: https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.random/-random/index.html

Comment: It's not accessible through `kotlin.random.Random` but this code is using `java.util.Random`. I'll update it to show that.

Comment: It't only for API 24 up

Comment: Is API 24 an Android thing? This isn't specifically for Android.

Comment: Note: if you're trying to generate a random password, for security, you should use `java.security.SecureRandom` instead of `java.utils.Random`. This will generate a truly random password.

Answer (score 167):

Since **Kotlin 1.3** you can do this:

```
fun getRandomString(length: Int) : String {
    val allowedChars = ('A'..'Z') + ('a'..'z') + ('0'..'9')
    return (1..length)
        .map { allowedChars.random() }
        .joinToString("")
}
```

Answer (score 75):

Lazy folks would just do

```
java.util.UUID.randomUUID().toString()
```

You can not restrict the character range here, but I guess it's fine in many situations anyway.

Comment: Caution, randomUUID() implementation of Java will always provide you a "4" as the "version" part of the UUID, which is why in the middle of the string there is always a 4, which does not make it completly random.

Comment: Live is full of surprises. Thanks for the clarification.

Answer (score 35):

Using [`Collection.random()`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/random.html) from Kotlin 1.3:

```
// Descriptive alphabet using three CharRange objects, concatenated
val alphabet: List<Char> = ('a'..'z') + ('A'..'Z') + ('0'..'9')

// Build list from 20 random samples from the alphabet,
// and convert it to a string using "" as element separator
val randomString: String = List(20) { alphabet.random() }.joinToString("")
```

Answer (score 12):

Without JDK8:

```
fun ClosedRange<Char>.randomString(length: Int) = 
    (1..length)
        .map { (Random().nextInt(endInclusive.toInt() - start.toInt()) + start.toInt()).toChar() }
        .joinToString("")
```

usage:

```
('a'..'z').randomString(6)
```

Answer (score 10):

To define it for a defined length:

```
val randomString = UUID.randomUUID().toString().substring(0,15)
```

where `15` is the number of characters

Comment: Caution, not all chars might be truly random. E.g. In Java implementation of UUID, "version" part of this string is fixed to 4, which is why the provided line will always have a 4 at the end.

Answer (score 8):

```
('A'..'z').map { it }.shuffled().subList(0, 4).joinToString("")
```

Comment: While this might answer the authors question, it lacks some explaining words and/or links to documentation. Raw code snippets are not very helpful without some phrases around them. You may also find [how to write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) very helpful. Please edit your answer - [From Review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/21498067)

Comment: This won't produce result with duplicated chars such as `aaaa` or  `aaxy` so it is not a random string generator.

Comment: Be aware that `('A'..'z')` also includes the characters `[`, \, `]`, `^`, `_` and `\``

Answer (score 6):

the question is old already, but I think another great solution (should work since Kotlin 1.3) would be the following:

```
// Just a simpler way to create a List of characters, as seen in other answers
// You can achieve the same effect by declaring it as a String "ABCDEFG...56789"
val alphanumeric = ('A'..'Z') + ('a'..'z') + ('0'..'9')

fun generateAlphanumericString(length: Int) : String {
    // The buildString function will create a StringBuilder
    return buildString {
        // We will repeat length times and will append a random character each time
        // This roughly matches how you would do it in plain Java
        repeat(length) { append(alphanumeric.random()) }
    }
}
```

Comment: Your answer is one of the highest performing ones here. For even better performance you can initialize the StringBuilder capacity by using `buildString(length) {...}` to avoid reallocations.

Answer (score 5):

Building on Fabb111's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67013680/8819027):

```
fun randomString(length: Int): String =
    buildString {
        repeat(length) {
            append((0 until 36).random().toString(36))
        }
    }
```

Numbers can be converted to a different base using the `Int.toString(Int)`.
Base 36 is the numeral system that contains all alphanumeric characters

Comment: wow, what sorcery is this!

Answer (score 4):

Using **Kotlin 1.3**:

This method uses an input of your desired string length `desiredStrLength` as an Integer and returns a random alphanumeric String of your desired string length.

```
fun randomAlphaNumericString(desiredStrLength: Int): String {
    val charPool: List<Char> = ('a'..'z') + ('A'..'Z') + ('0'..'9')

    return (1..desiredStrLength)
        .map{ kotlin.random.Random.nextInt(0, charPool.size) }
        .map(charPool::get)
        .joinToString("")
}
```

If you prefer unknown length of alphanumeric (or at least a decently long string length like `36` in my example below), this method can be used:

```
fun randomAlphanumericString(): String {
    val charPool: List<Char> = ('a'..'z') + ('A'..'Z') + ('0'..'9')
    val outputStrLength = (1..36).shuffled().first()

    return (1..outputStrLength)
        .map{ kotlin.random.Random.nextInt(0, charPool.size) }
        .map(charPool::get)
        .joinToString("")
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Or use coroutine API for the true Kotlin spirit:

```
buildSequence { val r = Random(); while(true) yield(r.nextInt(24)) }
   .take(10)
   .map{(it+ 65).toChar()}
   .joinToString("")
```

Comment: The advantage of coroutines is avoiding all these higher-order functions and writing a simple loop that does the equivalent of all of them. `(1..10).forEach { yield(r.nextInt(24) + 65).toChar() }`

Answer (score 2):

Building off the answer from Paul Hicks, I wanted a custom string as input. In my case, upper and lower-case alphanumeric characters. `Random().ints(...)` also wasn't working for me, as it required an API level of 24 on Android to use it.

This is how I'm doing it with Kotlin's [`Random`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.random/-random/index.html) abstract class:

```
import kotlin.random.Random

object IdHelper {

    private val ALPHA_NUMERIC = ('0'..'9') + ('A'..'Z') + ('a'..'z')
    private const val LENGTH = 20

    fun generateId(): String {
        return List(LENGTH) { Random.nextInt(0, ALPHA_NUMERIC.size) }
                .map { ALPHA_NUMERIC[it] }
                .joinToString(separator = "")
    }
}
```

The process and how this works is similar to a lot of the other answers already posted here:

1. Generate a list of numbers of length `LENGTH` that correspond to the index values of the source string, which in this case is `ALPHA_NUMERIC`
2. Map those numbers to the source string, converting each numeric index to the character value
3. Convert the resulting list of characters to a string, joining them with the empty string as the separator character.
4. Return the resulting string.

Usage is easy, just call it like a static function: `IdHelper.generateId()`

Answer (score 2):

I use the following code to generate random words and sentences.

```
val alphabet: List<Char> = ('a'..'z') + ('A'..'Z') + ('0'..'9')

val randomWord: String = List((1..10).random()) { alphabet.random() }.joinToString("")

val randomSentence: String = (1..(1..10).random()).joinToString(" ") { List((1..10).random()) { alphabet.random() }.joinToString("") }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
fun randomAlphaNumericString(@IntRange(from = 1, to = 62) lenght: Int): String {
    val alphaNumeric = ('a'..'z') + ('A'..'Z') + ('0'..'9')
    return alphaNumeric.shuffled().take(lenght).joinToString("")
}
```

Comment: While this may solve OP's problem (I have not tested), code only answers are generally discouraged on SO. It would be better if you could include a description as to **why** this is an answer to the question. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Here's a cryptographically secure version of it, or so I believe:

```kotlin
fun randomString(len: Int): String {
    val random = SecureRandom()
    val chars = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789".toCharArray()
    return (1..len).map { chars[random.nextInt(chars.size)] }.joinToString("")
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a simple function that uses newer Kotlin stdlib functions:

```kotlin
fun randomString(length: Int): String = 
  CharArray(length) { validChars.random() }.concatToString()


val validChars: List<Char> = ('a'..'z') + ('A'..'Z') + ('0'..'9'),
```

This uses:

- a [collection constructor with a initializer function](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/constructing-collections.html#initializer-functions-for-lists)

  ```kotlin
  CharArray(length) { i -> /* provide a value for element i */ }
  ```

  This is a one-liner for creating a `CharArray` and initializing each value using a lambda, It accepts a length, so the `CharArray` will be initialized with the correct size.
- The [`Collection<>.random()`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/random.html) extension function, that will pick a random character. This [can be seeded](https://github.com/JetBrains/kotlin/blob/ea836fd46a1fef07d77c96f9d7e8d7807f793453/libraries/stdlib/common/src/generated/_Collections.kt#L558) if desired.

  ```kotlin
  validChars.random()
  ```
- The initialized `CharArray` is converted to a string using [`concatToString()`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.text/concat-to-string.html), which was released in version 1.4.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `RandomStringUtils.randomAlphanumeric(min: Int, max: Int) -> String` from **apache-commons-lang3**

Answer (score 0):

I used the most voted answer, but after using it for a while I discovered a big problem, since the random strings weren't that random.
I had to modify the generation of the random character, since if I only left allowedChars.random() it always generated the same strings, and I couldn't find why. I was reading that because random() was called very quickly, but I don't know how it works when calling it on the list of numbers.

```
fun getRandomString(): String {
    val allowedChars = ('A'..'Z') + ('a'..'z') + ('0'..'9')
    var string = ""
    for (i in (1..20)) {
        string += allowedChars[(Math.random() * (allowedChars.size - 1)).roundToInt()]
    }
    return string
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 // initialise at top
 companion object {
    private const val allowedCharacters = "0123456789QWERTYUIOPASDFGHJKLZXCVBNM"
}

 //pass size and get Random  String Captcha
fun getRandomCaptcha(sizeOfRandomCaptcha: Int): String {
    val random = Random()
    val sb = StringBuilder(sizeOfRandomCaptcha)
    for (i in 0 until sizeOfRandomCaptcha)
        sb.append(allowedCharacters[random.nextInt(allowedCharacters.length)])
    return sb.toString()
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)

Answer (score -1):

The best way I think:

```
fun generateID(size: Int): String {
    val source = "A1BCDEF4G0H8IJKLM7NOPQ3RST9UVWX52YZab1cd60ef2ghij3klmn49opq5rst6uvw7xyz8"
    return (source).map { it }.shuffled().subList(0, size).joinToString("")
}
```

Comment: But isn't it, that this just mixes the characters (elements of the list) and thus every character would be chosen only once? Or am I missing something?