# How can we call a similar function from a class as on random numbers in kotlin:

Tags: android, kotlin

```
class Dice(val numSides: Int){
//function for rolling the dice
fun roll(): Int{
return (1..numSides).random()
}
```

Below is the complete program and wanted to know how to implement that for strings

```
fun main() {
    val myFirstDice = Dice(6)
    println("Your ${myFirstDice.numSides} sided dice rolled ${myFirstDice.roll()}!")
    
    val mySecondDice = Dice(20)
    println("Your ${mySecondDice.numSides} sided dice rolled ${mySecondDice.roll()}!")
}

class Dice (val numSides: Int) {

    fun roll(): Int {
        return (1..numSides).random()
    }
}
```

I wanted something along the lines of

```
fun main(){
   val myFirstFlip = Coin(2)
   println("Your Coin Flip result is ${myFirstFlip.flip()}!")
}

class Coin(val side: string){
    fun flip(): string {
        return arrayOf("H","F").random()
    }    
}
```

I am trying to go for this but it is not working, I wanted to get a random string from a list of strings specified as for the random numbers

Want to know how to implement a  function for strings in the same manner above in kotlin from a class.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: It is unclear what you are trying to achieve. Perhaps edit your question with a more detailed explanation? Also, have you tried something yourself? Can you show what you have so far?

Comment: fun main(){
   val myFirstFlip = Coin(2)
   println("Your Coin Flip result is ${myFirstFlip.flip()}!")
}

class Coin(val side: string){
 fun flip(): string {
        return arrayOf("H","F").random()
    }    
}   I am trying to go for this but it is not working, I wanted to get a random string from a list of strings specified as for the random numbers

Comment: When you say arrayOf("H","F").random() doesn't work, do you get an exception? an error?

Comment: It says Unresolved reference to string, but i got it thanks for the questioning just tweaked minor changes and got it.

Comment: fun main(){
   val myFirstFlip = Coin(2)
   println("Your Coin Flip result is ${myFirstFlip.flip()}!")
}

class Coin(val side: Int){
    fun flip(): String {
        return arrayOf("H","F").random()
    }    
}

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
fun main(){
   val myFirstFlip = Coin(2)
   println("Your Coin Flip result is ${myFirstFlip.flip()}!")
}

class Coin(val side: string){
    fun flip(): String {
        return arrayOf("H","F").random()
    }    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are asking how to generate a random string.

Look Here
[Idiomatic way to generate a random alphanumeric string in Kotlin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46943860/idiomatic-way-to-generate-a-random-alphanumeric-string-in-kotlin/49315602)

OR

https://www.baeldung.com/kotlin/random-alphanumeric-string