# Kotlin - how can I print limited length

Tags: android-studio, kotlin, generics

I tried to make password generator ( only string ) using Kotlin for-loop
when I run the code it's shows me outputs like this

```
OHDPETGDIKPCIQPHBHKWSQKXB
PJQBCSNRWDSHJJXFISDMBVAGT
XSEVXCONRMXQGHXDADQFNLJYK
```

its too long password so I tried to use some Kotlin functions (Size,Length) and didn't work with me maybe I just don't know the right way to do it , example I just want Password length size is from 5 to 15 chars
please forget the numbers variable and x variable

Kotlin Code:

```
class passwordMaker {


    private val password = ('a'..'Z') + ('A'..'Z')
    private val numbers = arrayOf(1,3,4,5,2,0,4,6,7,'@','#','_','/')




    fun passwordMaker(){

        var x = numbers
        var xy = password.subList(0,25)



        for (i in xy){



            print(xy.random())
            xy.size-3
            print((x.random()))
            x.size-4

        }



    }
}
```

Comment: What are you trying to do with `sublist()`? Currently, you're just limiting yourself to all the capital letters except for `'A'`. Can't really tell you how to fix the code without knowing what the rules of the password you're generating are. Also, I'm guessing you probably meant `'a'..'z'` instead of `'a..'Z'`. Lines like `xy.size - 3` don't do anything. It's just an expression that you're throwing away by not doing anything with the result.

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/a/73677850/4161471

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
class passwordMaker {

    fun getRandomPassword(a: Int): String {
        val characterSet =( 'a'..'Z') + ('A'..'Z')
        var random = Random(System.nanoTime())
        var password = StringBuilder()


        for (i in 0 until a){


            val psMaker = random.nextInt(characterSet.size)
            password.append(characterSet[psMaker])
        }

        return password.toString()
    }


}
```